# Using public keys as universally unique ids

Tags: public-key-infrastructure

When people want a universally unique id, tey usually use uuid or something similar to avoid collisions.

But new systems / protocols such as bitcoin and scuttlebutt use an RSA / AES public key derived from a private key as a unique id for the user or wallet.

What is the chance of a collision if you have billions of accounts?

Comment: Bitcoin uses a hash of an ECC (secp256k1) publickey, and there are several Qs already on bitcoin.SX about the collision risk.

Comment: Any results of that inquiry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Bitcoin ID is an ECC public key using the curve *SECP 256K1*, which means it is 256 bit long. The question if one of your billion keys ($10^{12}$) collide, is solved by the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). The probability that a collission occurs is approximately $p(10^12;2^256) = 1-(\frac{2^256-1}{2^256})^{10^12\frac{10^12-1}{2}}$ which is approximately $4 * 10^{-54}$.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the chance of a collision if you have billions of accounts?

The chance of collision with an RSA 2048 bit public key is very low, and I mean very very low even with that many accounts assumed it has been generated using a suitably secure (pseudo) random number generator.